# How to get a client-side object reference to a RadButton which is inside an EditTemplate of a FormView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, formview, rad-controls

I am trying to get a javascript reference to a RadButton object which is inside an EditTemplate. This is working fine with a RadTextBox but not with the RadButton. Looking at the generated code, I see that the ClientID of the RadButton instead of 
`ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployerFormView_rdBtnLegal`

it is

`ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployerFormView_rdBtnLegal_input`. As a result the javascript code below:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('<%=EmployerFormView.FindControl("rdBtnLegal").ClientID%>');
```

returns an undefined object reference. The strange thing, that I do not understand is why `<%=EmployerFormView.FindControl("rdBtnLegal").ClientID%>` evaluates to `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployerFormView_rdBtnLegal` (without the _input) and the ClientID is with the `_input`

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to read up on client/server controls and their effect on the final markup rendered in the browser. That'll answer part of your questions. Containers such as CPH's or telerik controls are going to output differently. Hence the ClientID.